why print(num) print '0'? num is global variable and I changed num to '6' in local function
When I compiled this code, I expected print(num) to print 6. The reason behind my expectation is that, firstly, the variable num is global. Thus, in the first line, num was reset to 0. Additionally, in the fifth line, print(average(7, 5, 9)), the function 'average' was defined. As the code was executed by the last line, num was changed from 7 to 6. Therefore, print(num) should have printed 6. However, it actually printed 0. Why did this situation occur? And what do I need to change to have 6 printed as num, referencing num1?
num = 0
def average(num1, num2, num3):
    num = num1
    return (num1 + num2 + num3) / 3
print(average(7, 5, 9))
print(average(6, 6, 7))
print(num)


It is global. It is also local in the context of your average() function


what do I need to change to have '6' printed as 'num'

You need to use global statement to change value outside function, simple example
num = 0
def set_num(n):
    global num
    num = n
set_num(100)
print(num)  # 100

